# Inconsistent Downstream and Upstream Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A boat takes $\frac{2}{3}$ as much time to travel downstream than to travel upstream. If the rate of the water is 8 kph, what is the rate of the boat in still water?

Correct answer is 40kph

Considering the following formulas:

> v $\leftarrow$ speed of boat
>
> x $\leftarrow$ speed of river
>
> v-x is for upstream
>
> v+x is for downstream

Also however, consider the wording: " A boat takes $\frac{2}{3}$ AS MUCH TIME to travel downstream". I am a bit confused here, does it pertain to ADDING time? as the boat goes downstream? downstream supposed to be faster so how can it add time? Does it pertain to multiplying $\frac{2}{3}$ to downstream or upstream? Any hint?

Comment: time downstream = 2/3*(time upstream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since time is distance over speed, the time (in hours) it takes for the boat to travel $1$ km going upstream is:
$$
\frac{1}{v + 8}
$$
Likewise, the time needed to go downstream is:
$$
\frac{1}{v - 8}
$$
So we must solve the equation:
$$
\frac{1}{v + 8} = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{v - 8}
$$